# How do you get the drive volume name or path drive using Get-WmiObject?

Tags: hard-drive, powershell

So I'm looking to find if a server has a shared drive, so far I've been able to find this Powershell coding.

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName Zetafax -Filter DriveType=3 | Select-Object DeviceID, @{'Name'='Size (GB)'; 'Expression'={[string]::Format('{0:N0}',[math]::truncate($_.size / 1GB))}}, @{'Name'='Freespace (GB)'; 'Expression'={[string]::Format('{0:N0}',[math]::truncate($_.freespace / 1GB))}}
```

This will only give me the letter ie C: or D:, is there a way to get it to show the path to show in the way Get-PSDrive does on a local pc?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but since you're looking for share information, wouldn't you be better off using the Win32_Share command for WmiObject?

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Share
```

This will give you the share name and the path. If you need more detail such as space and size, you will need to get that information using the first command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any commands, including the ones you use on a local machine on a remote machine using:

[PowerShell Remoting](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/remoting-the-implicit-way/)

[Invoking Remote commands](https://blog.ipswitch.com/how-to-run-commands-on-remote-computers-with-powershell)

[or WMI](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-run-wmi-commands-on-remote-computers/).

There are built-in cmdlets for this use case.

```
Get-Command -Name '*smbshare*' | 
Format-Table -AutoSize

CommandType Name                   Version Source  
----------- ----                   ------- ------  
Function    Block-SmbShareAccess   2.0.0.0 SmbShare
Function    Get-SmbShare           2.0.0.0 SmbShare
Function    Get-SmbShareAccess     2.0.0.0 SmbShare
Function    Grant-SmbShareAccess   2.0.0.0 SmbShare
Function    New-SmbShare           2.0.0.0 SmbShare
Function    Remove-SmbShare        2.0.0.0 SmbShare
Function    Revoke-SmbShareAccess  2.0.0.0 SmbShare
Function    Set-SmbShare           2.0.0.0 SmbShare
Function    Unblock-SmbShareAccess 2.0.0.0 SmbShare


# get function / cmdlet details
(Get-Command -Name Get-SmbShare).Parameters
Get-help -Name Get-SmbShare -Full
Get-help -Name Get-SmbShare -Online
Get-help -Name Get-SmbShare -Examples


Get-SmbShare

Name   ScopeName Path       Description  
----   --------- ----       -----------  
ADMIN$ *         C:\Windows Remote Admin 
C$     *         C:\        Default share
D$     *         D:\        Default share
E$     *         E:\        Default share
F$     *         F:\        Default share
IPC$   *                    Remote IPC
```